# Got "Dropbox access is not authorized. Error message: v1_retired" in KDE Cloud Storage Manager - what to do?

Tags: 16.04, kde, dropbox

I have installed KDE Storage Service Manager ([`storageservicemanager` package with version 4:15.12.3-0ubuntu1.1](https://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial-updates/storageservicemanager)) on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS with all updates.

And then tried to add Dropbox account to it. Got this window with error message:

> **Authentication Failed --- Storage Service Manager**
> Dropbox access is not authorized. Error message: v1_retired

[image: window with error]

What should I do to make it working with Dropbox?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems to be expected behavior, because of [API v1 shutdown](https://blogs.dropbox.com/developers/2017/09/api-v1-shutdown-details/):

> As previously announced, API v1 is being retired on Thursday, September 28th, 2017.
>
> On this date, API v1 endpoints will return a `400` error with this message:
> `{“error”: “v1_retired”}`. This means any integrations or applications still relying on API v1 endpoints may stop working.

So I reported [bug 1762408](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/kdepim/+bug/1762408) to LaunchPad.